# Is there a way to save a scene and exclude some assets in Godot?

Tags: godot

I have a procedurally generated texture. It is generated each time i open godot. Is there a way to tell godot not to save the texture into scene file? This currently is causing the scene to be big and causes issues with git.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to just generate your texture at runtime instead of inside the editor. If you *need* to generate the texture in-editor, and that texture is owned by one particular node you don't mind ignoring, you can unset the `owner` of that `Node` to [prevent Godot from saving it](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_packedscene.html#description).
To do this in-editor, use a `tool` script:

```
tool
extends Node

func _ready():
    owner = null
```

Finally, if you specifically need to isolate the `Resource` itself, have your generator save the texture into a separate `.png` file that `.gitignore`'d, and reference that texture from your node.

Comment: I'd recommend not setting owner to null like this. Save the generated texture as a resource, such as `Texture` or `ImageTexture` using `ResourceSaver.save()`.

Have the node that uses the texture use the saved resource. This will not embed it into the scene but it will create an external resource reference to the newly saved resource.